# ASP.NET MVC 2 site not loading after having moved to production. Setup appears to mimic QA fine. Thoughts?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I've setup an ASP.NET MVC 2 site several times on our test system on IIS 6. I'm fine with having to use the .aspx extension on controllers. The Global.asax.cs file looks like this:

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.html/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
          );

        routes.MapRoute(
          "Root",
          "",
          new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", id = "" }
        );

    }
```

Other than this, deployment is pretty basic. I copied the files to the server, created a new virtual directory in IIS, set Account.aspx as the default document, and clicked ok.

Repeating these same steps for production doesn't work. It seems like IIS 6/ASP.NET doesn't want to route correctly (even thought it did so just fine on our test server).

My url looks like this:

http://_server_name:90/<*IS APPLICATION NAME*/Account

The site load with the basic IIS 'site cannot be found'. The url has been changed to look like:

http://_server_name>:90/*IIS APPLICATION NAME*/CustomErrorView?aspxerrorpath=/_APPLICATION_NAME_/Account.aspx/Logon

(underscores begin and end place holder values and are not literally in the url).

CustomErrorView is a view I created for custom errors to forward to (including 404's).

Both servers are running windows 2003.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm an idiot. When deploying an asp.net mvc application, it helps to ensure mvc is installed on the server. I installed it through the web platform installer and, presto, everything worked.

Sorry about such a lame question. I was moving to production and the steps I just knew should work didn't work and I sort of panicked.

Thanks for your input Marco. Haven't had a chance to try that solution, but its running now.

Comment: You can also just make sure that the mvc dll is local-copied to your bin directory, so it is deployed automatically along with your app. That is what I do.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a Webform page that just redirect to your path!! And configure iis to point that page!!!! Let me know if was this scenario